# Storing files from a directory in variable names in python

Tags: python, csv, networkx

I have this:

```
directory = os.path.join("/home","path")
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
       if file.endswith(".csv"):
           f=open(file)
           f.close()
```

and 'files' contains about 300 csv files like:

```
['graph_2020-08-04_2020-08-17.csv',
 'graph_2020-04-11_2020-04-24.csv',
 'graph_2021-02-05_2021-02-18.csv',
...]
```

I basically want to add a name to each of these files, so that i have file1, file2, file3 ... for all of them. So if I call file1, it contains graph_2020-08-04_2020-08-17.csv for example. This is what i have:

```
for i in files:
    file[i] = files[i]
```

But it returns

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

What am I doing wrong in my approach?

Comment: You already *have* individual names for all of the files - `files[0]`, `files[1]`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

files is a list with strings in it, not integers. So when you say 'for i in files,' you are telling it that 'i' is a string. Then when you try to do file[i], it gives an error because you 'i' is a string, not an int. So instead of saying 'for i in files', you could say 'for i in range(files.size)' or something like that

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your question is that you have a list with n element. and you want to assign each element to n different variables. I can't understand why would you need this but:

1. @wolfenstein11x is right. with that for loop you'll have each element. However let's say you fix that. With the code you wrote you will assign each element of files to a list named file. (considering it has at least n element)

If what I understood is right and you really want n different variable for each element in files list (still I don't know why would you need it) you might take a look to exec.

Edit after reply:

You can read each file in a loop and do what ever with the content:

```
directory = os.path.join("/home","path")
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
        with open(file, "r") as conetnt:
            print(conetnt.read())
```

Comment: The reason I need this is because currently only the file is loaded and I need to rename them as something else, so that the file reads the file as a csv. So file1 = read_csv for that graph etc

Comment: To read each file you don't need to assign a variable for each filename.You can basically read each file in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the builtin function `exec()` to execute a string as Python code. An example of how to do this:

```
file_number = 1  # A counter to keep track of the number of files you have found
directory = os.path.join("/home","path")

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".csv"):
            exec("file" + str(file_number) + " = " + file)
            file_number += 1

print(file1)  # Example usage
```

I think this is what you wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Just go with the `enumerate(iterable,start)` function:

```
for i,file_name in enumerate(files): # or optionally you can pass a start position which by default is set to 0 and we don't need to modify it in your case
    file[i] = file_name
```

Do remember to initialize a seperate `file = []` list as i see you are using `file` as a loop variable and that way you can't pass it a value and an index,that way the program might throw an error. Do learn about the `enumerate()` function it saves a lot...Happy Coding..:)

Answer (score -1):

Use `for i in range(files.size)` instead of `for i in files`.

Comment: I cannot do that, as files contains the set of my csv files, so there is not attribute size.

Comment: @Isa files.size indicates number of actual files in the variable named files. When you do ```for i in files```, i is an iterator (string i.e. file_name) to each file, but when you do ```for i in range(files.size)```, i is an index, usually from 0 to N (where N is a total number of files). You can use i as an index only when it is an integer.